# Python: Variable from higher scope "referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, scope

Suppose I have a method foo:

```
def foo(string):
    def bar1():
        if '1' in string:
            string = string[2:]
        else:
            bar2()

    def bar2():
        if ('2' in string):
            string.insert(5, '1')
        else:
            string.insert(5, '2')

    bar1()
```

Unfortunately, this returns an error stating that local variable `string` was referenced before assignment. I thought that string would be inherited from `foo`'s scope. Was I wrong? Note that the variable `string` is actually a list (sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Try to pass string into bar1() like this: def bar1(string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments to variables create a new variable in the local scope, unless the `nonlocal` keyword is used (Python 3 only):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/